# function returns false when it should return true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a basic shape in Unity that turns within certain constraints with keyboard input. However, when I try to turn right from the extreme left side. It seems that the input isn't being called due to a function not returning true when, by all my understanding, it should.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aldd.png

Anyone know why this isn't returning true? Here is the rest of the script if needed:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ControlScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Rigidbody shipRig;
public int rotationSpeed = 1;
public int retRotationSpeed = 1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Rigidbody tempShipRig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Vector3 shipEuler = shipRig.rotation.eulerAngles;

    //up input
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.x, 0, 25) || 
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.x, 335, 360))
    {
        shipEuler.x = shipEuler.x + (-rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    //down input
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.x, 0, 25) || 
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.x, 335, 360))
    {
        shipEuler.x = shipEuler.x + (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if(shipEuler.x !=0) //idle return to center
    {
        if(shipEuler.x < 180)
        {
            shipEuler.x = shipEuler.x - (retRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            if(shipEuler.x < 0)
            {
                shipEuler.x = 0;
            }
        }
        if (shipEuler.x > 180)
        {
            shipEuler.x = shipEuler.x + (retRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (shipEuler.x > 360)
            {
                shipEuler.x = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //left input
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.z, 0, 45) || 
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.z, 315, 360))
    {
        shipEuler.z = shipEuler.z + (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    //right input
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.z, 0, 45) || 
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.z, 315, 360))
    {
        shipEuler.z = shipEuler.z + (-rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    if (shipEuler.x > 25 && shipEuler.x < 335) //fixes the rotation getting stuck when they pass over constraints
    {
        if(shipEuler.x < 180)
        {
            shipEuler.x = 25;
        }
        if(shipEuler.x > 180)
        {
            shipEuler.x = 335;
        }
    }
    if(shipEuler.z > 45 && shipEuler.z < 315)
    {
        if(shipEuler.z < 180)
        {
            shipEuler.z = 45;
        }
        if(shipEuler.z > 180)
        {
            shipEuler.z = 315;
        }
    }

    shipRig.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(shipEuler);
    shipRig = tempShipRig;

    Debug.Log(shipEuler);
}

bool CheckBounds (float orNr, float min, float max) //returns true if numbers are within constraints
{
    return (orNr <= max && orNr >= min);
}
}
```

Comment: Good time to learn how to use a debugger..

Comment: orNr was 45, max was 45, what about min?

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot without seeing the code that populates `x`, `y`, and `z` in your vector. Are you sure they are values between 0 and 360? E.g. maybe they get set to -180 thru 180, or something. I don't see any code that handles full rotation, e.g. by applying modulo after rotation.

Comment: min would be 0, as seen in `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.z, 0, 45) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && CheckBounds(shipEuler.z, 315, 360))`

shipRig.rotation.eulerAngles is (0.0,0.0,45.0)

Comment: not really related to your question but a suggestion:
instead of 

 if(shipEuler.x < 0)  shipEuler.x = 0;
 if(shipEuler.x < 0)  shipEuler.x += 360;

same for 
 if(shipEuler.x >360)  shipEuler.x = 0; should be
 if(shipEuler.x  >360)  shipEuler.x -= 360;

this way you won't loose information on the loop